# Angular Parent & Child Scope doesn't work in $root scope?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I found two examples about parent & child scope inheritance. However, 1st one is using parent and child controller, while 2nd example is using root scope. But 2nd example doesn't work as expected. What is the difference?

http://jsfiddle.net/angelohuang/kbUSb/
html 1

```
<div ng-controller="ParentCtrl">
  <div>Hello, {{data.message}}</div><br>
  <input type="text" ng-model="data.message">
  <div ng-controller="ChildCtrl"><br><br>
      <div>Hello 2, {{data.message}}</div><br>
  </div>
</div>
```

script 1

```
function ParentCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.data = {message: ''};
}

function ChildCtrl($scope) {
}
```

---

http://plnkr.co/edit/DBvSmO1fkmiOkH3sShSG

html 2

```
<input type="text" ng-model="data.message">
<div>Hello, {{data.message}}</div><br>

<div ng-controller="firstCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="data.message">
    <div>Hello 2, {{data.message}}</div>
</div>
```

script 2

```
var app = angular.module('application', []);

app.controller('firstCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second example the module 'application' isn't being used triggering this error:  [Argument 'firstCtrl' is not a function, got undefined](http://docs.angularjs.org/error/ng%3aareq?p0=firstCtrl&p1=not%20a%20function,%20got%20undefined).

This is because you give your module a name ('application') here:

```
var app = angular.module('application', []);
```

but start Angular without it:

```
<html ng-app>
```

Switch that line to this:

```
<html ng-app="application">
```

And it'll run as you expect.

[updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/09gxiEkeu3VTqmiJDbqg?p=preview)